# Where is libjsig.so in JDK 7 (Mac OS)?

Tags: java, jna

I need to set up LD_PRELOAD variable to path to libjsig.so, but I can find only libjsig.dylib. I use jdk 1.7 update 55. Where is libjsig.so in JDK 7 (Mac OS)?

Answer (score 1):

MacOS X does not use `.so` libraries but rather `.dylib`. It also doesn't use the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable but rather `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`.

Comment: Note that the native JNA code for OSX does not currently support protected mode.  At the time protected mode was implemented, libjsig did not exist on the OSX JVM (patches welcome).